# Which formats of 3D models are supported by Qt to use with OpenGL?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

Qt is involved here so I want to know which 3D models does Qt support when it works with OpenGL?

Is there a list somewhere  of the 3D model formats supported by Qt?

Comment: Copying your title into a well-known search engine, I got [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/Loading-a-3D-Model) in the top-10. Look for the paragrah "For a list of supported formats ..."

Comment: @Jongware Wow, I searched google for half an hour before asking here. Well, thankful to you.

Comment: It is pointing to this function: `QGLAbstractScene::supportedFormats()` which means I am supposed to write a code to find out which formats are supported! @Jongware

Comment: Sorry, I see that particular link is dead. Further searching tells me "Returns a list of all supported formats known by currently available sceneformat plugins, in the format type t", which explains why it's a function rather than a fixed list: it is extensible by code.

Comment: @Jongware See if you can convert that into a proper answer. I may select it.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't really support any 3d model formats. It supports rendering triangles out of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which 3D models does openGL support when it works with Qt?

None and everything!

There's nothing "special" when using OpenGL in a Qt application. The QtOpenGL wrappers are just convenience functions that help with context and function pointer management.

OpenGL by itself has ***no(!)*** support for 3D models whatsoever. It just draws points, lines and triangles by the programmers commands. The programmer (you) is programming a general purpose computing machine and thereby you can read and draw the contents of whatever 3D model format you're able to write a parser and OpenGL drawing code for; and by the virtue of running on general purpose hardware this is: Every 3D model format.

Of course it puts the burden on you to actually program it. That there is Qt involved does not matter at all.

Comment: While true for the sub-part "what formats does OpenGL support", OP specifically asks in the context of QT, which *does* support loading models. (I just edited the title to point that out. Do rollback if you find it inappropriate but I think the original wording lead to this misconception.)

Comment: @Jongware: Qt is a big framework constisting of dozens of libraries. *Some* of them support loading 3D models. But OP doesn't clarify which library she's talking about...

Comment: @peppe How do you know I am 'she'? BTW, I am working with QML and I need the openGL with QML. I don't know what libraries are needed.

Comment: I simply alternate between "she" and "he" when I don't know OP's gender. Back on topic, QML / Qt Quick themselves are not able to load any 3d model, they're mostly technologies for 2D content. Qt 3D (now in redevelopment) is instead able to load `.obj` or any format supported by [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) (if you have assimp on your system).